# Check for a character in a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

Python's `in` doesn't work on whole columns:

```
> dfTrain['name'][22]
  'McGowan, Miss. Anna "Annie"'

> "\"" in dfTrain['name'][22]
  True

> "\"" in dfTrain['name']
False
```

How can I check if a character is present in a *list* of strings?

Comment: try: `dfTrain['name'].str.contains('"')`

Comment: why bother escaping when you can do ' " '

Comment: dfTrain['name'].str.contains('"') works! How can I get just one value "True"? not a Series...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several ways of doing this:

1) One of the things you can do is

```
"\"" in dfTrain['name'].to_string()
```

This returns `True` if any of the names in the df contain a ".

2) The other way could be `not dfTrain[dfTrain['name'].str.contains('"')].empty`

This is because, I am finding all columns that contain `"`. 
If there are no columns that contain `"` it means the dataframe returned will be empty. 
If the dataframe returned is empty(True) then none of the columns contain a `"` for which you want the output 'False' (hence the 'not' statement')

Answer (score 4):

"\"" in dfTrain['name'][22] is 'McGowan, Miss. Anna "Annie"' which contains "\"

while dfTrain['name'] is a list and you dont have a "\" as element in list

Similar example as yours:

```
>>> nested_list_example = ["abhishek","ralesh","wr'"]
>>> "wr'" in nested_list_example
True
>>> "'" in nested_list_example
False
>>> "'" in nested_list_example[2]
True
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `join()` elements in each row into one string and use `contains()` in order to check whether it contains `"`:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
                                      name
0                           [test1, test2]
1                           [another test]
2                      [yet, another test]
3  [McGowan, Miss. Anna "Annie", aaa, bbb]

In [12]: df['name'].str.join('').str.contains('"')
Out[12]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: name, dtype: bool
```